# In JavaScript within a JSP, is there a way to open a Save As dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jsp, dialog

Can anyone tell me how to open a **Save As Dialog Box** in JSP?

`<a href="#" onClick="doSave()"> <img src="save.gif" alt="Save As"></a>`

I need to eliminate `doSave` in JavaScript and I have to implement this in a JSP.
I searched and the `execCommand` is not supported in Netscape browsers. Please provide a solution that is cross browser compatible. I have lost my two days with googling on this. :( :(

Comment: the above link is not working for me. i could not open the page

Comment: Just search for `jsp forced download`

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for this at all (it would also be impossible as that's a security breach). Just send a normal HTTP request to it which returns an "attachment" response. Before being able to answer this in detail, you need to tell what exactly you need to download and where exactly it is located in the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

We can't raise save as option automatically using jsp.Because save as is a client side option.
Only solution i got (without writing js) is the user have to save the file/image using right click say "save as".